# Double accent on single character

Tags: pdftex, accents

I wish to write the name of pdfTeX's author:

[image]

I am not able to figure out how to write the middle name. I tried`Th\'{\^{e}}`, but it doesn't return the desired output.

It's different from the similar double accent question: [Multiple diacritics on one character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159291/multiple-diacritics-on-one-character) since the answer there (using TIPA) doesn't work here. This is a very specific situation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Maybe this is related to [Multiple diacritics on one character](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159291/multiple-diacritics-on-one-character)?

Comment: ``H\`an Th\raise .5ex \rlap{\char19}\^e Th\`anh``?

Comment: Or use the plain ``H\`an Th\'{\^e} Th\`anh`` and typeset with XeLaTeX.

Comment: @HenriMenke if you're typesetting with XeLaTeX, you can use the unicode characters directly

Comment: @Au101 ...given that your keyboard layout allows you to type them directly.

Comment: @egreg I don't think that this is a duplicate. None of the answers in the other question actually handle the question how to correctly input a specific vietnamese character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a vietnamese name so for the best result you need a vietnamese font encoding:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

T5: {\fontencoding{T5}\selectfont H\`an Th\'\ecircumflex{} Th\`anh}

T1: H\`an Th\'{ê} Th\`anh
\end{document}
```

[image]

With xelatex or lualatex you can input the character (U+1EBF) directly or use the accent command from xunicode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Charis SIL}

\begin{document}
Hàn Thế Thành

Hàn Th^^^^1ebf Thành

Hàn Th\textcircumacute{e}  Thành

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Stefan Pinnow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/95441/stefan-pinnow)'s comment I found the solution:

using [stackengine](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stackengine?lang=en) package we can write:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\begin{document}
H\`an Th\stackon[3pt]{\^{e}}{\'{}} Th\`anh
\end{document}
```

Note: I couldn't find the desired symbol in [TIPA](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tipa) package.