# Unusual Accented Letter: umlaut + accent

Tags: accents

This is the letter I'm trying to reproduce: ǘ

There's an umlaut and, on top, an acute accent. I can do one or the other but not both.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Combining accents `\'{\"{u}}` works for me... (`pdftex` with with `fontenc`).

Comment: @campa You have to add option `T1`, because in many other options it doesn't work.

Comment: @JouleV Ups... I thought I wrote that... Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @campa Now you can write an answer ;)

Comment: This works: \'{\"{u}} Thanks Campa.

Comment: The stack on option also works: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159291/multiple-diacritics-on-one-character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
ǘ
\end{document}
```

works.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Not a problem down the line if it's not typeset, with brackets and all, as other accents are?

Comment: And actually, it doesn't work for me. The letter simply disappears. Btw, I'm using /book.

Comment: @nofare Do you have an up-to-date TeX distribution? Do you use Xe/LuaLaTeX as the compiler?

Comment: What doesn't work? This simple MWE or when you embed it into you larger document with all sorts of packages/options loaded?

Comment: Sorry should have been clearer: it doesn't work once embedded in a much larger document.

Comment: @nofare Could you add an example with a compilable code? I can't reproduce the problem. And of course, check all the warnings and the log file. Update the TeX distribution if necessary.