# Double diacriticaled letter

Tags: stacking-symbols

I'm an non-english speaker absolute newbie to latex and this forum (so many reasons to despair !). I'm trying to use it to write ancient greek.I've managed to make single-diacritical letters alright.
But I would like to stack a first diacrital sign for the accent (ó for example, made with `\'{o}`) with another diacrital for letter quantity (ō or ŏ, made with `\={o}` or `\u{o}` ).
With :

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,frenchb]{babel} 
\newcommand*{\tg}[1]{\textgreek{#1}}  
\begin{document} 
\tg{\={\'o}}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting
[image]
Which would be perfect, but I would like the acute diacritical on top.

With :

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,frenchb]{babel} 
\newcommand*{\tg}[1]{\textgreek{#1}} 
\begin{document} 
\tg{\'{\=o}} 
\end{document}
```

I'm getting
[image]
with the acute diacritical not on top, but on the left. :/
Any idea to solve this issue ?
Many thanks, o wise lateX wizards !

Comment: `\textacutemacron{o}` that is available when using the `tipa` package could be interesting.

Comment: See also: [Multiple diacritics on one character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159291/134144)

Comment: I like your final invocation, but I'd prefer ‘o wise watex lizards!’…

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `teubner` package that is specifically for philological typesetting of Greek.

```latex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,frenchb]{babel} 
\usepackage{teubner}
\newcommand*{\tg}[1]{\textgreek{#1}}  
\begin{document} 
\tg{a\Am{a}\Gm{a}\Cm{a}o\Am{o}\Gm{o}\Cm{o}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Table 4 in the manual lists the commands for double diacritics.