# How to typeset two symbols

Tags: symbols

I am wondering if it is possible to typeset two symbols like ^ and ~ over a letter.
My idea was something like ^{~{u}}, but it does not work.

Something similar is discussed in: [How to typeset the symbol “^” (caret/circumflex/hat)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77646/how-to-typeset-the-symbol-caret-circumflex-hat)

Unfortunately, only one symbol is explained there.

Comment: Yes, of course. Tilde is usually written as `\~{a}` and Zirkumflex as `\^{a}`, but you can, of course, combine the too: `\~{\^{a}}`, or simply use a modern LaTeX engine like LuaLaTeX and use the character as is: ẫ. 

For u there is no precomposed Unicode codepoint, however, and your font might be missing the required glyphs. Expect mixed results.

Comment: Hi Noah, welcome! Do you want the symbols in math mode or in text mode? There are different approaches...

Comment: It would be great, if it is possible in text mode.

Comment: @Ingmar Yes, I tried that. However, it does not work, \^ will be above the letter but \~ will be next to the letter, for \~{\^{a}}. :(

Comment: Unfortunately û̃ is not a pre-composed character, so your font needs to support combing glyphs.

Comment: Try using solutions in [accents - Multiple diacritics on one character - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159291/multiple-diacritics-on-one-character) first.