# How to write an i-breve WITH an an acute accent on top (eg, "Latin Small Letter i with Breve and Acute")?

Tags: accents, diacritical-mark

How would I go about either making or indicating this character (the example here is from the Blackfoot Native American language)?:

[image: Latin Small Letter i with Breve and Acute]

In context, the number 7: ixkits´ĭka, kits´ĭka :
[image: 7 ixkits´ĭka, kits´ĭka]

And full context, Blackfoot (Siksiká / ᓱᖽᐧᖿ) numerals one through ten:

[image: Blackfoot numerals one through ten]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.TX! Did you see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159291/47927 ?

Comment: If you are using modern Unicode Open Type fonts that have a Combining Diacritical Marks block, you can do direct input of U+0069 LATIN SMALL LETTER I, U+0306 COMBINING BREVE, U+0301 COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT to get ĭ́̆́.

Comment: Very interesting @Cicada. I can't actually see your example in this website's preferred font of apparently Helvetica on macOS Chrom*: https://share.getcloudapp.com/z8ubXzwW - but - when I view it in an app like Pages and change the font to Times New Roman it renders like this: https://share.getcloudapp.com/z8ubXzXp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For convenience and quicker input if you do not have a Blackfoot keyboard, a set of macro shortcuts could be defined.

Decide on a naming convention to make them easier to remember/read.

Example:

[image: niso]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}       
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\newcommand\sikibrvac{\char"0069\char"0306\char"0301}
\newcommand\sikaac{\char"0061\char"0301}
\newcommand\sikeac{\char"0065\char"0301}
\newcommand\sikiac{\char"0069\char"0301}
\newcommand\sikoac{\char"006F\char"0301}
\begin{document}
n\sikiac{}so kits\sikibrvac{}ka. \sikaac\sikeac\sikoac.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

For such cases, using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX is best.

I propose three possible inputs. In the first one I use a macro (that can be clearer when maintaining the code); the second one uses the combining acute U+0301 next to “i with breve”; the third one uses “i” followed by the combining breve U+0306 and the combining acute U+0301.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Gentium Plus}

\newcommand{\ba}[1]{% breve acute
  #1^^^^0306^^^^0301%
}

\begin{document}

nitókska ixkits\ba{i}ka

nitókska ixkitsĭ́ka

nitókska ixkitsĭ́ka

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer. Your answer is as equally valuable to me as @Cicada's, but since they have fewer points, I decided to chose them as the answer for this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, for heavy-duty linguistics work, a customizable ASCII transliteration-scheme input-method using only a standard keyboard could be handy if direct input and custom keyboard are not available.

[image: ascii]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}       
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}



\newcommand\BFmapsto[2]{%
\noindent #1 $\mapsto$ {#2}\par
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

        \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \seq_gset_split:Nnn 
            { cno }

    \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \tl_count_tokens:n 
            { V }
            

    \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \tl_greplace_all:Nnn
            { Nxx }         
            
            

    \int_new:N 
            \l_fc_rweqz_int
    \int_new:N 
            \l_fc_rweqy_int

%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \fc_funcshowmap:n #1 { 
    % 1=translit pair from;to
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { #1 }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_tl %from
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                                {1} 
                    }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_fc_rweqy_tl %to 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                                {2} 
                    }                   
                    \BFmapsto {\l_fc_rweqz_tl} {\l_fc_rweqy_tl}
                    
}
    
%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \fc_functranslit:n #1 { 
    % 1=translit pair from;to
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { #1 }
%           \seq_show:c 
%                   { l_fc_rweqz_seq } 
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_tl %from
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                                {1} 
                    }
%           \tl_show:N 
%                   \l_fc_rweqz_tl %from
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_fc_rweqy_tl %to 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                                {2} 
                    }                   
            \tl_greplace_all:Nxx
                \g_myBFts_tl
                { \l_fc_rweqz_tl }
                { \l_fc_rweqy_tl }
%           \tl_show:N 
%               \g_myBFts_tl
                    
}



%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \ic_funcsortseq:cn #1#2 { % 1=seq, 2=order (<:descending, >:ascending) 
    \seq_sort:cn  { #1 } %\l_fc_rweq_seq 
        {
            \seq_clear:N 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
            \seq_clear:N 
                    \l_fc_rweqy_seq 
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { ##1 }
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_fc_rweqy_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { ##2 }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_tl 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                                {1} 
                    }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_fc_rweqy_tl 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_fc_rweqy_seq 
                                {1} 
                    }

            \int_set:Nn 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_int 
                    { 
                        \tl_count_tokens:V 
                                \l_fc_rweqz_tl 
                    }
            \int_set:Nn 
                    \l_fc_rweqy_int 
                    { 
                        \tl_count_tokens:V 
                        \l_fc_rweqy_tl 
                    }
            \int_compare:nNnTF 
                    { \l_fc_rweqz_int } { #2 } { \l_fc_rweqy_int }
                    { \sort_return_swapped: }
                    { \sort_return_same: }
        }
}


%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \doBFshowmap:n #1 { 
            \exp_args:Nx
            \seq_map_function:cN 
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #1 _seq } 
                    \fc_funcshowmap:n
    
    }



%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \doBFtransts:n #1 { 
%           \seq_show:c 
%                   { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #1 _seq } 
            \exp_args:Nx
            \seq_map_function:cN 
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #1 _seq } 
                    \fc_functranslit:n
    
    }


%--------------------
\NewDocumentCommand { \mfsloadaseq } { o m +m } { 
% 1=namespace
% 2=seq name
% 3=data

                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fc_namespace_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fc_namespace_tl { #1 } }


    \cs_if_free:cT
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq }
            { \seq_new:c
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
                }
    \seq_gclear:c 
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
    \seq_gset_split:cno 
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
            { , } 
            { #3 }
}


%--------------------
\NewDocumentCommand { \mfssortaseq } { o m m } { 
%1=namespace
%2=seqname, 
%3=><, asc/desc

                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fc_namespace_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fc_namespace_tl { #1 } }

\ic_funcsortseq:cn { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } { #3 }

}


\NewDocumentCommand { \blackfoot } { m } {%
\BFtrans {#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \BFtrans } { O{ts} m } {%
\cs:w BFtrans#1 \cs_end: {#2}
}
\tl_new:N \l_myBFts_tl 
\NewDocumentCommand { \BFts } { m } { \BFtransts {#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand { \BFtransts } { m } {%
\tl_gset:Nn \g_myBFts_tl { #1 }
\doBFtransts:n {BF}
\tl_use:N \g_myBFts_tl
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \BFmap } { } {%
%\tl_gset:Nn \g_myBFts_tl { #1 }
\doBFshowmap:n {BF}
%\tl_use:N \g_myBFts_tl
}



\ExplSyntaxOff

%%%%%%


\mfsloadaseq{BF}{
a';á
,e';é
,i';í
,ib';ĭ́
,o';ó 
}
\mfssortaseq{BF}{<}





\begin{document}

\blackfoot{ni'so}

\blackfoot{a' e' i' ib' o'}

\noindent Transliteration Scheme

\BFmap

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{cl}
1 & \blackfoot{nito'kska, nise'a}\\
2 & \blackfoot{na'toka} \\
3 & \blackfoot{niuo'kska, niuo'ka} \\
4 & \blackfoot{nisoo', niso', ni'so} \\
5 & \blackfoot{nisito', ni'sito} \\
6 & \blackfoot{na'u} \\
7 & \blackfoot{ixkitsib'ka, kitsib'ka} \\
8 & \blackfoot{na'niso} \\
9 & \blackfoot{pi'xkso} \\
10 & \blackfoot{ke'po} \\
100 & \blackfoot{kiipi'ppo} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

*Edit*

Probably `-*` and `--*` are more practical as the transliteration scheme:

[image: ascii 2]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}       
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\usepackage{multicol}



\newcommand\BFmapsto[2]{%
\noindent #1 $\mapsto$ {#2}\par
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

        \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \seq_gset_split:Nnn 
            { cno }

    \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \tl_count_tokens:n 
            { V }
            

    \cs_generate_variant:Nn 
            \tl_greplace_all:Nnn
            { Nxx }         
            
            

    \int_new:N 
            \l_fc_rweqz_int
    \int_new:N 
            \l_fc_rweqy_int

%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \fc_funcshowmap:n #1 { 
    % 1=translit pair from;to
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { #1 }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_tl %from
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                                {1} 
                    }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_fc_rweqy_tl %to 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                                {2} 
                    }                   
                    \BFmapsto {\l_fc_rweqz_tl} {\l_fc_rweqy_tl}
                    
}
    
%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \fc_functranslit:n #1 { 
    % 1=translit pair from;to
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { #1 }
%           \seq_show:c 
%                   { l_fc_rweqz_seq } 
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_tl %from
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                                {1} 
                    }
%           \tl_show:N 
%                   \l_fc_rweqz_tl %from
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_fc_rweqy_tl %to 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                                {2} 
                    }                   
            \tl_greplace_all:Nxx
                \g_myBFts_tl
                { \l_fc_rweqz_tl }
                { \l_fc_rweqy_tl }
%           \tl_show:N 
%               \g_myBFts_tl
                    
}



%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \ic_funcsortseq:cn #1#2 { % 1=seq, 2=order (<:descending, >:ascending) 
    \seq_sort:cn  { #1 } %\l_fc_rweq_seq 
        {
            \seq_clear:N 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
            \seq_clear:N 
                    \l_fc_rweqy_seq 
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { ##1 }
            \seq_set_split:Nnn 
                    \l_fc_rweqy_seq 
                    { ; } 
                    { ##2 }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_tl 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_fc_rweqz_seq 
                                {1} 
                    }
            \tl_set:Nx 
                    \l_fc_rweqy_tl 
                    { 
                        \seq_item:Nn 
                                \l_fc_rweqy_seq 
                                {1} 
                    }

            \int_set:Nn 
                    \l_fc_rweqz_int 
                    { 
                        \tl_count_tokens:V 
                                \l_fc_rweqz_tl 
                    }
            \int_set:Nn 
                    \l_fc_rweqy_int 
                    { 
                        \tl_count_tokens:V 
                        \l_fc_rweqy_tl 
                    }
            \int_compare:nNnTF 
                    { \l_fc_rweqz_int } { #2 } { \l_fc_rweqy_int }
                    { \sort_return_swapped: }
                    { \sort_return_same: }
        }
}


%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \doBFshowmap:n #1 { 
            \exp_args:Nx
            \seq_map_function:cN 
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #1 _seq } 
                    \fc_funcshowmap:n
    
    }



%------------------
    \cs_set:Npn \doBFtransts:n #1 { 
%           \seq_show:c 
%                   { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #1 _seq } 
            \exp_args:Nx
            \seq_map_function:cN 
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #1 _seq } 
                    \fc_functranslit:n
    
    }


%--------------------
\NewDocumentCommand { \mfsloadaseq } { o m +m } { 
% 1=namespace
% 2=seq name
% 3=data

                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fc_namespace_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fc_namespace_tl { #1 } }


    \cs_if_free:cT
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq }
            { \seq_new:c
                    { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
                }
    \seq_gclear:c 
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
    \seq_gset_split:cno 
            { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } 
            { , } 
            { #3 }
}


%--------------------
\NewDocumentCommand { \mfssortaseq } { o m m } { 
%1=namespace
%2=seqname, 
%3=><, asc/desc

                \IfNoValueTF { #1 } 
                        { \tl_clear:N \g_fc_namespace_tl } 
                        { \tl_gset:Nn \g_fc_namespace_tl { #1 } }

\ic_funcsortseq:cn { g_fc_rwe \g_fc_namespace_tl #2 _seq } { #3 }

}


\NewDocumentCommand { \blackfoot } { m } {%
\BFtrans {#1}
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \BFtrans } { O{ts} m } {%
\cs:w BFtrans#1 \cs_end: {#2}
}
\tl_new:N \l_myBFts_tl 
\NewDocumentCommand { \BFts } { m } { \BFtransts {#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand { \BFtransts } { m } {%
\tl_gset:Nn \g_myBFts_tl { #1 }
\doBFtransts:n {BF}
\tl_use:N \g_myBFts_tl
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \BFmap } { } {%
%\tl_gset:Nn \g_myBFts_tl { #1 }
\doBFshowmap:n {BF}
%\tl_use:N \g_myBFts_tl
}



\ExplSyntaxOff

%%%%%%


\mfsloadaseq{BF}{
a';á
,e';é
,i';í
,ib';ĭ́
,o';ó 
,a*;á
,e*;é
,i*;í
,i**;ĭ́
,o*;ó
,-*;́
,--*;̆́
}
\mfssortaseq{BF}{<}





\begin{document}

\blackfoot{ni'so}

\blackfoot{a' e' i' ib' o'} :: \blackfoot{a* e* i* i** o*} :: \blackfoot{A-* E-* I-* I--* O-* A-*a}

\noindent Transliteration Schemes

\begin{multicols}{4}
\BFmap
\end{multicols}

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{cl}
1 & \blackfoot{nito'kska, nise'a}\\
2 & \blackfoot{na'toka} \\
3 & \blackfoot{niuo'kska, niuo'ka} \\
4 & \blackfoot{nisoo', niso', ni'so} \\
5 & \blackfoot{nisito', ni'sito} \\
6 & \blackfoot{na'u} \\
7 & \blackfoot{ixkitsib'ka, kitsib'ka} \\
8 & \blackfoot{na'niso} \\
9 & \blackfoot{pi'xkso} \\
10 & \blackfoot{ke'po} \\
100 & \blackfoot{kiipi'ppo} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice advice, thank you.